# i have an issue with iScroll4 when I change the orienatation from portrait to landscape on iPhone

Tags: iphone, landscape, iscroll4

I have an issue with iScroll4 when I change the orienatation from portrait to landscape. It is working on AppMobi XDK, but on iPhone, it is not rendering properly. I have tried to trap the orientationchange event and called the refresh method of iScroll with different timeout values, but no luck.

Comment: Not rendering problem means dynamic loading or scrolling issue?

Answer (score 2):

please use jq.scroller.js from the link:

https://github.com/appMobi/jQ.Mobi/tree/master/plugins

It is easy to use with like this:

```
 var options={
  verticalScroll:true, //vertical scrolling
  horizontalScroll:false, //horizontal scrolling
  scrollBars:true  //display scrollbars
  vScrollCSS : "scrollBarV", //CSS class for veritcal scrollbar 
  hScrollCSS : "scrollBarH", //CSS class for horizontal scrollbar
  refresh:true, //Adds 'Pull to refresh' at the top
  refreshFunction:updateMessage //callback function to execute on pull to refresh
}

var scroller = $("#my_div").scroller(options);
```

Replace #my_div with your Div ID.It will work perfectly.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug with iScroll.  I'm a developer at appMobi, and lead developer of jqMobi and our scrolling library does not have this problem.